# is there any way to make android device run as ftp/sftp server over internet "not in local" by java?

Tags: java, android, ftp, nfs

I tried to make android as FTP server 
it's a success in the local network by the library

I am tried by [swiftp](https://github.com/ppareit/swiftp)  library but it's work only in local network 
in `swiftp` lib you must open wifi or open hotspot wifi `torun` server and you can access to your files in local by FTP protocol  
I want to make app like `swiftp` but work over the internet that can access to my android files from anywhere!
any help?

Comment: Do you make difference between ftp and sftp?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.

You stated that your phone would use a simcard to connect to the internet.

Your phone can run a server but you will not get incoming connections from the internet as your cellcard provider blocks them.